# Did Microsoft change Random default seed?

Tags: c#, random

Today, I was doing some tests in .NET Core, and I have come across some interesting thing.

Before (~ .NET Framework 4), `Random` used `Environment.TickCount`, but now I believe this has changed.

Consider the following code:

```
while (true)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    Console.WriteLine(random.Next(0, 10000));
}
```

In older .NET Framework versions, the `new Random()` empty constructor would use Environment.TickCount, which would lead to repetition of pseudo-random values.

So you could expect results like:

```
542
4211
5244
5244
5244
9501
9501
```

so on and so fourth.

On the latest .NET Core version using the latest compiler, I have received the following result:

```
5332
220
3928
524
2973
2840
4965
5667
657
6434
3170
3046
7044
```

Which is definitely improved.

Other S.O questions demonstrating this behaviour in older versions:

[How do I generate a random int number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number)

[generate random numbers with no repeat in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675211/generate-random-numbers-with-no-repeat-in-c-sharp)

[Non-repetitive random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011198/non-repetitive-random-number)

[Is C# Random Number Generator thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049467/is-c-sharp-random-number-generator-thread-safe)

---

My setup: .NET Core 2.2 / latest C# compiler.

---

**The actual question**

So my question is, has the PRNG really improved or they just changed constructor to use another default seeds, and, if so, what they're using as a seed? Is it safer now for cryptography (if they actually changed the implementation)?

Comment: `Is it safer now for cryptography?` No. As in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8):  "To generate a cryptographically secure random number, such as one that's suitable for creating a random password, use the RNGCryptoServiceProvider class or derive a class from System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator"

Comment: The problem is that you´re recreating a new `Random` again and again. You should create it once and only once.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I know about it, and it's exactly what I'm saying. On older versions, it would repeat the number multiple times, but on newer version it's not.

Comment: @dyukha I thought as much, but if its internals has changed (which I'm not sure about), then maybe they have made something extra. Not certain.

Comment: @AxelKemper I believe the referenceseource is outdated. It's using the default constructor as TickCount, and if I use Environment.TickCount directly I'll have the old and repeated result.

Comment: @bradbury9 that source is for .Net Framework, not dotnet core.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the latest version of dotnet core, the `Random` default constructor assigns its seed from a hidden private instance of `Random`. The private instance uses Interop.GetRandomBytes for its seed. New instances use the private instances's `Next()` result as its seed.

This basically makes it 'safe' to create several random instances in a loop.

Read more on the corefx GitHub:

Related code files: [Private Random Instance](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/452c93e38097b53f19516486fda4f3b1f16334cf/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Random.cs#L118), [Default Constructor - Generate Seed](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/452c93e38097b53f19516486fda4f3b1f16334cf/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Random.cs#L124)  and [Private Random Instance - Generate Seed](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/452c93e38097b53f19516486fda4f3b1f16334cf/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Random.cs#L144).

Seed change pull request [Parameterless constructor seeding improvement #1919](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/2192)

Comment: This is smart. Thanks for your answer, I wasn't aware of this change. Is it only for corefx I presume?

Comment: As of .Net Framework 4.8, the default seed is still `Environment.TickCount`

Comment: Any ideas why corefx has a different implementation?

Comment: Not sure, but my guess is that Microsoft is mainly working on dotnet core, and it is *safer* to allow multiple instances, instead of leaving unwanted results from having multiple instances. Even if multiple instances aren't in a tight loop, there might be several instances in separate classes.

Comment: Maybe the wanted to get rid of the enviroment? .net core is supposed to be platform agnostic so they would not relay on `Enviroment.TickCount`.

Comment: After some digging through the corefx issues on GitHub, I found [this one related to the random seed](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1919), which references [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/2192)